# Como puedo obtener los datos de una tabla para poder guardarlos en la base de datos?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Trato de obtener los datos de la siguiente tabla para poder usar los datos y guardarlos en la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no entiendo como llegar a esos datos ya que he tratado de usar js para acceder a esos datos mediante innerhtml o innerText pero a la hora de enviar los datos al controlador este me arroja null en el parametro que envio con los datos de la tabla.

```
<script>
$("#btnDatos").click(function () {

    var tabla = document.getElementById("trDato");
    
    console.log(tabla);

    var params = {
        listaPedido: tabla
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Pedido/ListarPedido',
        data: params,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            $("#txtListado").val(response.listadoFinal);
        },

    });
})
```

He buscado varias formas de como hacerlo pero siempre me llega null al controlador

```
 [HttpGet]
 public JsonResult ListarPedido(string listaPedido)
    {
        var lista = listaPedido;
        
        string listadoFinal = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista);

        return Json(new { listadoFinal }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Agredeceria mucho si alguien me orientara en este tema

Comment: Agrega el código de lo que es `btnDatos`,  `trDato` y `txtListado` para tener un [example] y poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Ayer estuve intentando implementar algo parecido pero enviando un listado de enteros, primero cree una variable de array y despues mediante el metodo push, fui insertando los numeros, la configuracion de mi peticion Ajax es esta.  content: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                      dataType: 'json',
                      data: { listIdPersonal: listadoIds },                                                       Del lado del Controller recibo un List<long> listIdPersonal. Importante que el parametro que recibe tiene que tener el mismo nombre que el que envia

Comment: tuve que hacer algo parecido usando javascript recorri cada elemento guardandolo en un array una vez armado lo envie mediante un json al controlador y hay manipule los datos